# GAS & HtmlService embedded in google site href management

Tags: html, google-apps-script, navigation, google-sites

I'm working on a Google Site:

- An input page uses HtmlService with a form that fills a line in a spreadsheet.
- An edit page shows the data  with handsometable gadget.

In every handsometable's line, there is a link to edit some information using the same script of the input page.

All works fine, but I have some problems after submit.

In the input page it's ok, with this code

```
<a  href="">new input</a>
```

The href is filled with the script url, clicking the link I go to input page.

In the edit page I'd like to go back to the page with the table, with this code:

```
<a  href="https://sites.google.com/a/www.xxx.it/test/edit">table</a>
```

but using the link I open the Google site in a frame into the page..

can i do something?

Thanks 
Marco

Hope this image better explain the question...

[some snapshoots http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/3748/OUzFV1.jpg](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img537/3748/OUzFV1.jpg)

Comment: Can you take a screen shot with something like the "Snipping Tool" and load an image into this question, so we can see where the link should be navigating to?

Comment: i have added some screenshot

Comment: Hi, still fighting with this problem.... and using SandboxMode.IFRAME for better performance and mobile compatibility the <a href=""> doesnt work anymore!!! Does anyone have a workaround? Is Google working on it?